# Add a class to get_the_term_list output

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, output

I have the following code:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'themes', '', '', ''); ?>
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
<a href="https://www.domain.test/themes/dark/" rel="tag">Dark</a>
<a href="https://www.domain.test/themes/white/" rel="tag">White</a>
```

The question is... how can I add a class to the output? I would like the result to be something like...

```
<a href="https://www.domain.test/themes/dark/" class="custom" rel="tag">Dark</a>
<a href="https://www.domain.test/themes/white/" class="custom" rel="tag">White</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show the 'get_the_term_list' function, changes have to make in this function

Comment: are you using WordPress?

Comment: @NickParsons yes, I'm using WordPress.

Comment: @JacobK. can you show the `get_the_term_list` function?

Comment: @NickParsons I can't find the function. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have need to use custom loop to add the class.

```
  <?php
    $themes = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'themes');
    if ($themes && ! is_wp_error($themes)): ?>
        <?php foreach($themes as $theme): ?>

            <!-- The slug is the URL of taxonomy,  defined at the time of registration taxonomy within 'rewrite'.-->
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $theme->slug, 'themes'); ?>" rel="tag" class="custom <?php echo $theme->slug; ?>"><?php echo $theme->name; ?></a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```